# Get chi squared from cartesian points

Tags: r, statistics, probability, p-value, chi-squared

I have a table with x, y columns

```
 x  y
10  12
23  24
12  43
34  15
74  18
...
```

How can I know if they have a random distribution or if there is a dependency between them?

Comment: Do you mean find out if the two variables are correlated? Both variables might be non-random but completely uncorrelated, or correlated but random. Even if they are correlated, that doesn't mean one is _dependent_ on the other. Are they measures of the same variable, or two different variables? Details matter here. Can you try to tell us a bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your tags suggest that you're after a chi-squared test. Presumably, you've already tried the obvious `chisq.test(c(10,23,12,34,74), c(12,24,43,15,18))`. What is wrong with that?